# Change the iteration step in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to compute the standard deviation for every 20 cells in the same column.

The equation that I am using is `STEDIV`. Now if I want the excel to learn to compute `STEDIV(A21:A40)` from `STEDIV(A1:A20)`, is there a way to make it happen?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do here. You just want to increase the range by 20 each time? Is there a specific place you're trying to put the results? Why isn't doing it by hand a practical solution? What happens if there aren't 20 cells in a group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear. 
Do you mean that you want to set
`B1` to `STEDIV(A1:A20)`, `B2` to `STEDIV(A21:A40)`, `B3` to `STEDIV(A41:A60)`, etc? 
If so, set `B1` to

```
=STEDIV(INDIRECT("A" & (ROW()-1)*20+1 & ":A" & ROW()*20))
```

and drag/fill down. 
The subexpressions `(ROW()-1)*20+1` and `ROW()*20` evaluate to `1` and `20` (respectively)
when evaluated in Row 1, `21` and `40` in Row 2, `41` and `60` in Row 3, etc. 
The rest of the inner expression builds a range reference: “`A1:A20`”, “`A21:A40`”, “`A41:A60`”, etc. 
And `INDIRECT()` turns a string that looks like a cell or range reference
into an actual reference that can be processed by any Excel worksheet function
that can take such a reference as an argument.

Answer (score 5):

With a nod to @Scott, using `INDIRECT` is a volatile function.  The same result can be achieved non-volatile with `INDIRECT`

```
=STDEV(INDEX(A:A,(ROW()-1)*20+1):INDEX(A:A,(ROW()*20)))
```

Assumes data and formulas start in row 1

Note: Stnadard deviation function is `STDEV` (or `STDEV.S` or `STDEV.P` in Excel 2010 or later)

Comment: Some interesting further detail on [volatile functions here](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/volatile-dependencies-indirect-dependencies-false-dependencies-when-dependencies-dont-work-the-way-you-think-they-should/)

Comment: @brettdj great info, Charles is a gold mine for this kind of stuff!